# MacOS, Connect Oracle SQL Dev Data Model to Oracle Cloud AD Warehouse?

Tags: oracle, cloud, oracle-sqldeveloper

After asking Bard, ChatGTP and search, I ask the public. I want to connect my Oracle SQL Dev Data Modeler to my Oracle Cloud Autonomous Data Warehouse (ADW) instance. SQL Dev version is 23.1. I can not find  a tab to create connections. Who knows steps to add connection? ChatGTP recommended that I use use Oracle SQl Dev Data Modeler on Microsoft Windows (I kid you not!). Please advise on using version 23 SQL Dev Data Modeler on a Mac. Old versions on Windows I already have ;-}

Comment: When you open sqldev, you have a connection panel open, and you have a '+' icon that allows you to add connections. Are you saying you don't have these in sqldev? Once you add a connection and be sure that it works, you can use the 'file' menu 'data modeler=>import=>'data dictionary' ' and it will ask you which connection you want to use, from those you already have.

Comment: In MacOS there is no menu item connection panel.  If you know how to access tell us. We use the latest Oracle SQLDEV. What you are suggesting was apparently removed more than 1 year ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm replying here to your comment just to show a print screen:
You have something like this when you open sqldev

[image]

You can use it to add connections (the + icon)

Comment: Screenshot is a different product, older version, Windows? I am looking at SQL Developer Data Modeler. My objective is to use the data modeler to architect the schema and then modify the cloud db as needed. I currently do something similar with MSSQL and Visual Studio, I want to replicate that experience using Oracle. Hope this clarifies. If you tried Toad or DBeaver on Mac connecting to Oracle Cloud Autonomous Data Warehouse (ADW) instance, I want to know if either is better than SQL Developer Data Modeler

Comment: Download sqldeveloper and use it's data modeler module. Do not use the data modeler by itself.

Comment: Thank you! One last question. In Tools menu there is a sub menu Data Modeler (and Help -> About -> Extensions). Is this referencing my previously installed Data Modeler or I should remove the previously installed version, it is redundant. I can't find the answer?  THANK YOU AGAIN!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can connect ORACLE Datamodeler to your Cloud instance by using "File>Import>Data dictionary" and then in the wizard that will be presented, add a new connection, selecting the "Connection type>Cloud wallet" and entering the path to the ZIP file of the wallet you should have downloaded from your Cloud instance. The Authentification type and the Role should be the default ones. User name/password as usual.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this previously, before posting the question. I downloaded a zip file, but the required file format required by the dialog is XML. What you write makes sense, but because the file filter type is exclusively XML, I stopped there. There is no XML in the ZIP, I checked.

Comment: Tested here on M1 with version OracleDataModeler 22.2.0.165 Build 165.1149 and it works with the cloud wallet ZIP file I used with SQLDeveloper, DBEaver. sqlcli and instantclient_19_8.

Comment: (And just downloaded version 23.1.0.087 build 087.0806 to be sure and it works also with this version)

Comment: Thank you, I do not have the same menu options, I can not explain the discrepancy. Closest I come is: Import Connections - Step 1 of 4 window, [Browse...] button
Navigate to the extracted Wallet directory  and changed file type to *.properties
file ojdbc.properties is shownn, double click selects and closes this dialog
[Next] button
Nothing happens. I am looking at the other tools. Thank you.

Comment: Import Connections is to import connections you have previously Exported from DataModeler or SQLDeveloper: NOT to import ojdbc.properties of the wallet!

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassing, I found a Youtube that shows me what to do. Thank you for your contributions.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6oaUtQqeKM